# run `perf stat` on the output of `perf record`?

Tags: linux, performance, optimization, perf

With [`perf` (the Linux profiler)](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page), (v4.15.18), I can run `perf stat $COMMAND` to get some simple stats on the command. If I run `perf record`, it saves lots of data to a `perf.data` file.

Can I run `perf stat` on the output of `perf record`? So that I can look at the perf recorded data, but also get a simple overview?

Comment: Related: it seems `perf stat report` only works with data saved by `perf stat record`, not regular `perf record`.

Answer (score 3):

`perf stat` uses [hardware performance monitoring unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_performance_counter) in counting mode, and `perf record`/`perf report` with perf.data file uses the same unit in overflow mode. In both modes [hardware performance counters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_performance_counter) are configured with control register into some kind of performance events (for example cpu cycles or instructions executed), and counters will be incremented on every event.

In counting mode `perf stat` will configure counters as zero at program start, and will read final counter value at program exit (actually counting may be split in several segments with same result - single value for full run).

In profiling mode ([sampling profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)#Statistical_profilers)) `perf record` will configure counter to some negative value, for example `-100000` and overflow handler will be installed (actual value will be autotuned into some frequency). Every 100000 events the counter will overflow into zero and generate an interrupt. `perf_events` interrupt handler will record the "sample" (current time, pid, instruction pointer, optionally callstack in `-g`) into ring buffer which will be saved into `perf.data`. This handler will also reset the counter into `-100000` again. So, after long enough run there will be thousands of samples to be stored in `perf.data`, which can be used to generate statistical profile of program (which parts of program did run more often).

What does `perf stat` show? In default mode for x86_64 cpu: running time of the program (task-clock and elapsed), 3 software events (context switch, cpu migration, page fault), 4 hardware  counters: cycles, instructions, branches, branch-misses:

```
$ echo '3^123456%3' | perf stat bc
0
 Performance counter stats for 'bc':
        325.604672      task-clock (msec)         #    0.998 CPUs utilized          
                 0      context-switches          #    0.000 K/sec                  
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
               181      page-faults               #    0.556 K/sec                  
       828,234,675      cycles                    #    2.544 GHz                    
     1,840,146,399      instructions              #    2.22  insn per cycle         
       348,965,282      branches                  # 1071.745 M/sec                  
        15,385,371      branch-misses             #    4.41% of all branches        
       0.326152702 seconds time elapsed
```

What does record `perf record`? In single wake up event (ring buffer overflow) it did save 1246 samples into perf.data, and default hw event was used (cycles)

```
$ echo '3^123456%3' | perf record bc
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.049 MB perf.data (1293 samples) ]
```

With `perf report --header|less`, `perf script` and `perf script -D` you can take a look into the perf.data content:

```
$ perf report --header |grep event
# event : name = cycles:uppp, , size = 112, { sample_period, sample_freq } = 4000, sample_type = IP|TID|TIME|PERIOD ...
# Samples: 1K of event 'cycles:uppp'
$ perf script 2>/dev/null |grep cycles|wc -l 
1293
```

There are some timestamps inside perf.data and some additional events for program start and exit (`perf script -D |egrep exec\|EXIT`), but there is no enough information in default `perf.data` to fully reconstruct `perf stat` output. Running time is recorded only as timestamps of start and exit, and of every event sample, software events are not recorded, only single hardware event was used (cycles; no instructions, branches, branch-misses). Approximation of used hardware counter can be done, but it is not exact (real cycles was around 820-825 mln):

```
$ perf report --header |grep Event
# Event count (approx.): 836622729
```

With non-default recording of `perf.data` more events can be estimated:

```
$ echo '3^123456%3' | perf record -e cycles,instructions,branches,branch-misses bc
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.238 MB perf.data (5164 samples) ]
$ perf report --header |egrep Event\|Samples
# Samples: 1K of event 'cycles'
# Event count (approx.): 834809036
# Samples: 1K of event 'instructions'
# Event count (approx.): 1834083643
# Samples: 1K of event 'branches'
# Event count (approx.): 347750459
# Samples: 1K of event 'branch-misses'
# Event count (approx.): 15382047
```

So, you [can't run `perf stat` on `perf.data` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14086859/196561), but you can ask `perf report` to print the header with event count estimation. You also can try to parse timestamps from `perf script`/`perf script -D`.

Comment: Is this question not a duplicate of [Can perf-stat results be generated from a perf.data file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10321073)?  I was going to close it, but then saw you posted similar answers on both.

Comment: Unless the question means something else, I think it is a duplicate one.

Comment: @osgx, may I ask you a lil bit further on your "profiling mode" vs "counting mode"
Basically, I used simpleperf tool on Android, which is based on Linux perf. I run the exact same program use "simpleperf stat" and "simpleperf record" with same duration respectively, I got the Instruction counts differed by around 15% however. Can you explain this weird phenomenon, please?
Because according to your explanation above, I think "stat" should be identical with "record" does...

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. perf record output is a data file. perf stat expects an application.
You can use perf script to run a pre-canned scripts that aggregate and summarize the trace data. Possible scripts can be listed using following command.
perf script -l
Beside limited number of pre-canned script, You can also define custom perf.data processing scripts in python or perl.
See [perf script](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/perf-script.1.html), [perf script in python](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/perf-script-python.1.html) and [perf script in perl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/perf-script-perl.1.html) for details.

Comment: Is there a script that gives output like `perf stat`, given a perf.data from `perf record`? This would be a useful answer if you showed one.  That's obviously what the question really wants, regardless of clumsy phrasing.

Comment: `perf report --header |egrep Event\|Samples` does estimation on total event count from `perf.data` file, but it is not precise and limited only to events, recorded into `perf.data` file.